# Methods in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am still learning Pharo, but it is a bit confusing. There two classes, `CarRental` and `Car`, and a `Test` class, `CarRentalTest`.

There are fixed number of cars, the same car cannot be rented twice, I have the code, but there is a mistake.

```
| carRental redPanda yellowPanda blackTesla |
    carRental := CarRental new.
    redPanda := Car panda.
    yellowPanda := Car panda.
    blackTesla := Car tesla.
    carRental
        addCar: redPanda;
        addCar: yellowPanda;
        addCar: blackTesla.
    self assert: carRental availableCars size equals: 3.
    carRental rent: redPanda days: 5.
    self assert: carRental availableCars size equals: 2.
    self assert: carRental rentedCars size equals: 1
```

I tried to initialize the `availableCars` and `rentedCard` methods, but there is still an issue.

Comment: Please describe the "issue".

Comment: when I try compile the code, I have the issue "the message availableCars & rentedCards sent but not implemented"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of rented cars, right? To do that add the ivar `rented` to the `CarRental` class and initialize it to an empty collection:

```
rented := OrderedCollection new.
```

(in other words, include the line above in the `#initialize` method - instance side.)

Now, every time you rent a car add it to the `rented` collection:

```
rent: aCar
  rented add: aCar
```

and when the car is returned

```
return: aCar
  rented remove: aCar
```

Also you can add the getter method which was missing so far

```
rentedCars
  ^rented
```

and compute the cars available for rent as

```
availableCars
  ^cars copyWithoutAll: rented
```